# Authorization problem between Rails and MongoDB Atlas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to follow the official doc to use mongoDB atlas on my rails application.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/current/reference/rails-integration/

But I have the following error that appears when I want to create or read :

```
# Mongo::Error::OperationFailure in PostsController#create
\[8000:AtlasError\]: (Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command { insert: "posts", $db: "admin", ordered: true, writeConcern: { w: "majority" }, txnNumber: 1.000000, lsid: { id: {4 \[129 103 129 204 83 248 73 51 140 2 11 71 126 35 223 247\]} } } (on ac-xjgsx9t-shard-00-02.whzyr5q.mongodb.net:27017, modern retry, attempt 1)
```

Even when I try to save it manually :

```
3.0.0 :003 \> post = Post.new(title: "Please", body: "Help me stack overflow")

=\> #\<Post \_id: 63f590426e92a40ae84042bb, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, title: "Please", body: "Help me stack overf...

3\.0.0 :004 \> post.save

/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/mongo-2.18.2/lib/mongo/operation/result.rb:364:in \`raise_operation_failure': \[8000:AtlasError\]: (Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command { insert: "posts", $db: "admin", ordered: true, writeConcern: { w: "majority" }, txnNumber: 1.000000, lsid: { id: {4 \[235 127 224 68 69 252 76 207 177 72 92 1 135 84 190 63\]} } } (on ac-xjgsx9t-shard-00-02.whzyr5q.mongodb.net:27017, modern retry, attempt 1) (Mongo::Error::OperationFailure)
```

This is my mongoid.yml :

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: mongodb+srv://hiddenuser:hiddenpassword@cluster0.whzyr5q.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
      options:
        server_selection_timeout: 5
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work...

I have tried everything... I tried with old versions of MMR (following the corresponding doc). Nothing works.

I created my cluster on Atlas, authorized the ip, verified that the user has all the powers... I even added another user with the status atlasAdmin...

And if I enter a wrong password, it writes me this error:

```
Mongo::Auth::Unauthorized in PostsController#create
User admin (mechanism: scram) is not authorized to access admin (auth source: admin, used mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-1, used server: ac-xjgsx9t-shard-00-02.whzyr5q.mongodb.net:27017 (PRIMARY)): [8000:AtlasError]: bad auth : authentication failed (modern retry, attempt 1)
```

So my password is correct since the begin...

Is there something I missed? Do I have to create a collection on Atlas first?

Thanks for your help!

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

The mistake came from here:

```
mongodb+srv://hiddenuser:hiddenpassword@cluster0.whzyr5q.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

You have to put the name of a collection before the ?retry :

```
mongodb+srv://hiddenuser:hiddenpassword@cluster0.whzyr5q.mongodb.net/NAMEOFYOURCOLLECTION?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Answer (score 0):

- For me, it worked by setting it like this:
  mongodb+srv://**hiddenuser**:**hiddenpassword**@**clusterUrl**/**NAMEOFDATABASE**?retryWrites=true&w=majority.
- So instead of solution above in the question, difference is to set
  just name of db you want before ?retry, collection will be automatically created when you add first element to it, or you can add it by setting it same name as model.